# Cannot find default inbox after updating to Office 365

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that looks for a specific subject line in an email on Outlook and grabs the attachment from the email.

We merged our emails with a corporate buyout and updated our Microsoft accounts to Office 365. Aside from this, my original VBA code should work since it doesn't look for any specific email folder. All references for Outlook are checked.

I get "nothing" for olMi and it exits the if statement.

```
Function Report()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Items
Dim olMi As MailItem
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Attachment
Dim MyPath As String
Dim wB As Workbook

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set rng = Nothing

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

subj = "Scheduled Report - Instructor List"

Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & subj & Chr(34))

''___> I get "OlMi = Nothing" here and it used to work
If Not (olMi Is Nothing) Then
    For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments
        olAtt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\Instructor\Desktop\temp\Instructor_Master.xls"
    Next olAtt
Else
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Have you inspected the collection `olItms` using the `VBA debugger` to find out what's going on?

Comment: I tested the code (added reference to Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library and updated the subj search string for my testing) and it worked ok. As Axel said, put it into debug because there's something else going on outside of the core code.

Comment: try to go by index through your olItms and go step by step, just to look what your subject may look like

Comment: I got it to work, however, I had to specify the email folder I wanted to search. Like this             Set olFldr = GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("reports@domain.com").Folders("Inbox")

Answer (score 0):

The default mailbox can change.

To determine the current default mailbox.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub defaultAfterUpgrade()

Dim defInbx As Folder
Dim defMailbox As Folder
Set defInbx = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set defMailbox = defInbx.Parent
Debug.Print "The default mailbox is: " & defMailbox.name

End Sub
```

As you found, when this occurs you have to change to the long version of referencing an inbox that includes the mailbox name.